# Can We directly Run the Deployed Reports in ReportServer using RS.EXE or using Report Service Script file?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, data-driven, rs.exe

Using RS.EXE utility, I deployed my reports in ReportServer Successfully.

I can run the deployed reports in my server manually.

Is there any way to run the deployed reports using RS.EXE utility or using RSS file?

Answer (score 1):

RS.exe can be used to render a SSRS report as following in this blog post http://sqlblog.com/blogs/roman_rehak/archive/2009/06/12/ssrs-report-rendering-from-command-prompt.aspx